# rake generate/deploy error : Not a directory @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages, octopress

I am using Octopress to generate a githubpage. 
I run rake generate to generate publics, following their [documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/).

```
$ rake generate
write source/stylesheets/screen.css
Configuration file: C:/Users/Username/Documents/octopress/_config.yml
        Source: source
   Destination: public/git@github.com:Username
  Generating...
  jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Not a directory @ dir_s_mkdir -C:/Users/Username/Documents/octopress/public/git@github.com:Username
## Set the codepage to 65001 for Windows machines
## Generating Site with Jekyll
```

and the mistake happened when I use

> rake deploy

it says that      `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master`

As you may have guessed, I am doing this alone to build up my blog though jekyll and githubpages, and there are no collaborators. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0):

[Deploying to Github Pages](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) necessitates that you first setup Octopress with :

```
rake setup_github_pages
```